# How to interpret the equivalent circuit of a true bipolar SAR ADC?

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb, circuit-design, adc, mixed-signal

I am referring to ADS8548 ([Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads8568.pdf)).

How do I interpret this equivalent circuit of the input of the ADC?
`CH_XX` would be where the analog voltage is fed and AGND would be grounded. There is a node called out as `VDC`, I'm not sure what this means?
I understand the ADC performs acquires, then converts but across which capacitor does the ADC take the analog voltage?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this simplified model, Cs represent the internal sampling capacitor array. Inside the real SAR ADC, this is actually a whole array of switched capacitors which are all charged in parallel during the track phase. This model doesn’t show how the SAR actually converts the voltage measured across Cs once the sampling capacitor is disconnected from the inputs; it’s just intended to help model the input network during the sampling time interval. Vdc is just a reference voltage level.

On a single-ended SAR ADC, the model would have only one Cs sampling array equivalent capacitor, but in this bipolar model, they show the sampling array as two Cs capacitors. Both of them are the input sampling array, they just chose to draw this model with the “middle” of the array called out by the Vdc point.

They could have drawn the sampling capacitor array in more detail, which might look like a bunch of capacitors connected by switches, with powers-of-two weights for the capacitor values, and each switch connecting to either Vref (Vdc) or ground. And there would also be a comparator shown, that determines whether each successive bit should be 1 or 0. That’s the simplified, naive model. Real SAR ADC could have more complicated arrangements, to get faster conversion speed. But that’s just background on how SAR works, it’s outside the scope of this model. The Cs just stands for the entire sampling array, during the time interval when it is in sample acquisition mode. Conversion mode isn’t addressed by this model.

The purpose of a model like this one, is to help design the input filter network. Not only do you select an RC filter that provides anti-aliasing (since frequency aliasing can’t be magicked away by clever DSP techniques), but also allows the sampling capacitor array to charge up within the allotted acquisition time. To use a model like this, you have to also account for the source impedance of whatever is being measured.

SAR ADCs work by redistributing the charge on the internal capacitor array, and at the end of that sampling, the capacitor array will be at a different voltage than the source being measured. As a result, when the sample acquisition begins, there is some charge injection from the sample capacitor back into the measurement source. If the measurement source is relatively high-impedance, and there’s no input RC filter, and you put an oscilloscope on the ADC input, you can sometimes actually see a glitch that results from this charge injection.

As long as the measurement source is able to recover and charge up the sample capacitor array to the correct value within the allowed acquisition time (at least to 1/2 LSB accuracy), then the charge injection glitch doesn’t matter.

If the measurement source is somewhat high impedance, or if the ADC is using a fast acquisition time, it can be challenging. The input RC network functions as an additional charge reservoir, recharging while the ADC is performing its conversion. If the input RC has a large enough C, larger than the sampling capacitor, then the charge injection glitch isn’t as noticeable.

Often the purpose of publishing a model such as this one in a data sheet, is to let the customer know the typical/design values of the equivalent resistance of the track/hold switch and the capacitance of the sampling array. Those aren’t tested min/max values found in the Electrical Characteristics table, but they’re important enough for design work that they usually are mentioned in the data sheet.

Comment: Beautifully explained

Comment: Shouldn’t node Vdc=0 during acquisition phase and Vdc= Vref during conversion phase?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct, Vdc node is switched like that. That’s what causes the first stage of charge redistribution, which lets the comparator determine the MSB. Again, the actual internal circuit could be more complicated, but you’ve got the right idea.